# Teams connector - ActionCard of type HttpPost returns Forbidden

Tags: microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I currently working on a Microsoft Teams Connector. The connecting flow and sending messages works fine, but when I have problems with actions of type 'HttpPOST'. The buttons are shown correctly, but when I click on it I get an error response: An unexpected error(Type = Forbidden) occurred. Please try again.

The call never reach the ngrok portal, so I think the error is related to how I send the message or how I configure the connector, but I couldn't find a solution.

I post:

```
{
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "@context": "https://schema.org/extensions",
    "summary": "Card \"Test card\"",
    "themeColor": "0078D7",
    "title": "Card created: \"Name of card\"",
    "sections": [
        {
            "activityTitle": "Miguel Garcia",
            "activitySubtitle": "9/13/2016, 3:34pm",
            "activityImage": "https://connectorsdemo.azurewebsites.net/images/MSC12_Oscar_002.jpg",
            "facts": [
                {
                    "name": "Board:",
                    "value": "Name of board"
                },
                {
                    "name": "List:",
                    "value": "Name of list"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Assigned to:",
                    "value": "(none)"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Due date:",
                    "value": "(none)"
                }
            ],
            "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
        }
    ],
    "potentialAction": [
        {
            "@type": "ActionCard",
            "name": "Add a comment",
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "@type": "TextInput",
                    "id": "comment",
                    "isMultiline": true,
                    "title": "Enter your comment"
                }
            ],
            "actions": [
                {
                    "@type": "HttpPOST",
                    "name": "OK",
                    "target": "https://401dd384.ngrok.io/teamshook/actions"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "@type": "OpenUri",
            "name": "View in web",
            "targets": [
                {
                    "os": "default",
                    "uri": "http://google.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I also set the ngrok url in the Connectors Dev Portal as valid domain and action url.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.5",
  "id": "9f849570-f95a-11e9-a986-c11672ed410c",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "packageName": "test",
  "developer": {
    "name": "Test GmbH",
    "websiteUrl": "https://test.io",
    "privacyUrl": "https://www.test.io/en/privacy-policy/",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.test.io/en/terms-and-conditions/"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "test",
    "full": "test"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "The test connector for the development environment.",
    "full": "The test connector for the development environment."
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "blue-bot_192px.png",
    "color": "blue-bot_32px.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#D85028",
  "configurableTabs": [
    {
      "configurationUrl": "https://401dd384.ngrok.io/testTab/config.html",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
      "scopes": [
        "team"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "staticTabs": [],
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "cc7e39e5-a336-43ec-956f-8c4a3326faae",
      "needsChannelSelector": true,
      "isNotificationOnly": false,
      "scopes": [
        "team",
        "personal"
      ],
      "commandLists": [
        {
          "scopes": [
            "team",
            "personal"
          ],
          "commands": [
            {
              "title": "Help",
              "description": "Shows help information"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "connectors": [
    {
      "connectorId": "c16f86d9-12b6-40ff-8314-745c4023f48c",
      "configurationUrl": "https://401dd384.ngrok.io/testConnector/config.html",
      "scopes": [
        "team"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "composeExtensions": [],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "401dd384.ngrok.io"
  ]
}
```

I inspect the web version of Teams and this post happen when I clicked the button:

```
curl -X POST \  'https://teams.microsoft.com/api/mt/emea/beta/users/connectors/xxx@thread.skype;messageid=xxx/executeAction' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 980caf3b-d35c-4b7f-bb64-6e36f1adb774' \
  -H 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' \
  -H 'authority: teams.microsoft.com' \
  -H 'authorization: Bearer xxx' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache,no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'cookie: display-culture=en-GB; MC1=GUID=47e1e76e0c7d4d6b9e5c726a58ea4556&HASH=47e1&LV=201909&V=4&LU=1569223617444; market=DE; MSCC=1569223618; smcflighting=100; clocale=en-gb; WT_FPC=id=2f7aca4e774166b49f41572934143837:lv=1572934143837:ss=1572934143837; MicrosoftApplicationsTelemetryDeviceId=9d964974-4082-a701-6c6b-41477ff7e6bd; MicrosoftApplicationsTelemetryFirstLaunchTime=1573132947473; MSFPC=GUID=47e1e76e0c7d4d6b9e5c726a58ea4556&HASH=47e1&LV=201909&V=4&LU=1569223617444; MUID=0D348A65E5EC65C502F287AFE4266466; MUIDB=0D348A65E5EC65C502F287AFE4266466; TSPREAUTHCOOKIE=true; deviceId=28a0b2a0-e350-46f2-bc29-b3b68e5149b1; firstTimeLaunch=1573464555718; TSREGIONCOOKIE=emea; minimumVersionClientUpdateTries=0; authtoken=Bearer=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IkJCOENlRlZxeWFHckdOdWVoSklpTDRkZmp6dyIsImtpZCI6IkJCOENlRlZxeWFHckdOdWVoSklpTDRkZmp6dyJ9.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.G9C3ZLa0j9uODExuszARtXfIspwiFf6_SIhBRjtqYnbMP6OxTkCOzatVIFwo_ZvKXng-v9YbHC7QImI0wPUocom2fOUdkLzBdCuuqLeWCvnhdBDCP7y6Nom0B2WBx2ulnlpl6L6E2LGR3K-oopK_cAZRy81qUAjV0gsCOgB7zPshSSeMbz_Z9wZmKtolhh3GaHtCH28IGfOVQoVc_P32oMPIflLBLLPynlKv_f7ICcRA77JpOzuLSG0ZykfR8BSpf-D-Hoe6wvgSrBFQcm4UESLpGQ5lDokfUp-deGogVTA6U-X LN2R71SV4D6BVXaKJVNpISBZ0C0u34EQ0fWdtcw&Origin=https://teams.microsoft.com; files-version=20191015024; sessionId=597a5c74-c0a8-6a28-b9e9-1ac3e4cb26f8; TSAUTHCOOKIE=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IkJCOENlRlZxeWFHckdOdWVoSklpTDRkZmp6dyIsImtpZCI6IkJCOENlRlZxeWFHckdOdWVoSklpTDRkZmp6dyJ9.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.aLKqzoCn4-I0VeGeM_MvHITyyfH6b-2gqJYB3ZvhYlhANojYSh6hBY1rwzaUYboeSpPbflzqpWlbZFUsowLHfEOdwRbLQmYcGBKWx10YkwAVyNDQd4hvz61MrITyZqY3iUuNf8hqAeZSuGHgE-i7nLqEydTQrvnQFLG_qMF9KWhMidiT7p2ULyBdNhvwkDEHsq378lykz4ZCvk1tVOzWETcv9xz_zFP0tffz6aHZ4FTsK2lkZuHmSMxwTNzGaXwZYEP2rzXbuz70GMRdJRmAfMJMzMD97IeV5MD3p230-3dY_M-hZp9EyAb2h9sACDQ7XYBMeTFTzCVYfkJoSOEA_Q; ARRAffinity=0b20ba151314f86a0737223ef48ad813dc527c505a17f75b2d96c6573ffe5df1' \
  -H 'origin: https://teams.microsoft.com' \
  -H 'pragma: no-cache' \
  -H 'referer: https://teams.microsoft.com/_?lm=deeplink&lmsrc=homePageWeb&cmpid=WebSignIn' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'x-ms-client-env: msteams-web-prod-euno-01' \
  -H 'x-ms-client-type: web' \
  -H 'x-ms-client-version: 1415/1.0.0.2019110122' \
  -H 'x-ms-scenario-id: 505' \
  -H 'x-ms-session-id: 995133f1-466e-6584-adb4-116d0c58a9d1' \
  -H 'x-ms-user-type: user' \
  -H 'x-ringoverride: general' \
  -H 'x-skypetoken: xxx' \
  -b 'display-culture=en-GB; MC1=GUID=47e1e76e0c7d4d6b9e5c726a58ea4556&HASH=47e1&LV=201909&V=4&LU=1569223617444; market=DE; MSCC=1569223618; smcflighting=100; clocale=en-gb; WT_FPC=id=2f7aca4e774166b49f41572934143837:lv=1572934143837:ss=1572934143837; MicrosoftApplicationsTelemetryDeviceId=9d964974-4082-a701-6c6b-41477ff7e6bd; MicrosoftApplicationsTelemetryFirstLaunchTime=1573132947473; MSFPC=GUID=47e1e76e0c7d4d6b9e5c726a58ea4556&HASH=47e1&LV=201909&V=4&LU=1569223617444; MUID=0D348A65E5EC65C502F287AFE4266466; MUIDB=0D348A65E5EC65C502F287AFE4266466; TSPREAUTHCOOKIE=true; deviceId=28a0b2a0-e350-46f2-bc29-b3b68e5149b1; firstTimeLaunch=1573464555718; TSREGIONCOOKIE=emea; minimumVersionClientUpdateTries=0; authtoken=Bearer=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IkJCOENlRlZxeWFHckdOdWVoSklpTDRkZmp6dyIsImtpZCI6IkJCOENlRlZxeWFHckdOdWVoSklpTDRkZmp6dyJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2FwaS5zcGFjZXMuc2t5cGUuY29tIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zdHMud2luZG93cy5uZXQvMzYyMDdkMTMtNTA1OC00Njg4LThiZjktMzIwMTM5OTk1ODk0LyIsImlhdCI6MTU3MzQ2NDI1NiwibmJmIjoxNTczNDY0MjU2LCJleHAiOjE1NzM0NjgxNTYsImFjY3QiOjAsImFjciI6IjEiLCJhaW8iOiJBU1FBMi84TkFBQUF6T1lpQ0JMdW1VM3JwZHNYUXNDT1JPWHp0a0lqRGtLY0YzN2E2U1RIYTYwPSIsImFtciI6WyJwd2QiXSwiYXBwaWQiOiI1ZTNjZTZjMC0yYjFmLTQyODUtOGQ0Yi03NWVlNzg3ODczNDYiLCJhcHBpZGFjciI6IjAiLCJmYW1pbHlfbmFtZSI6IkJvcm5lbWFubiIsImdpdmVuX25hbWUiOiJTdmVuIEJvcmlzIiwiaXBhZGRyIjoiOTAuMTg3LjQ4LjQ5IiwibmFtZSI6IlN2ZW4gQm9yaXMgQm9ybmVtYW5uIiwib2lkIjoiZjdiYzI1ZTUtZWFhZi00NzBlLWIyMTgtZjAyYWEzMDAwZDcxIiwicHVpZCI6IjEwMDMzRkZGOTMwMzMxMkYiLCJzY3AiOiJ1c2VyX2ltcGVyc29uYXRpb24iLCJzaWduaW5fc3RhdGUiOlsia21zaSJdLCJzdWIiOiIxZ0NqOTNUZFpCV1hkOU1OQnRxUGVXR1lDQkM1REhxNTVOV1ctZlFCS3c4IiwidGlkIjoiMzYyMDdkMTMtNTA1OC00Njg4LThiZjktMzIwMTM5OTk1ODk0IiwidW5pcXVlX25hbWUiOiJzdmVuQGhlbGxvaHEuaW8iLCJ1cG4iOiJzdmVuQGhlbGxvaHEuaW8iLCJ1dGkiOiIwQUVMb1F0VlZVS0tOdkIySE14NUFBIiwidmVyIjoiMS4wIn0.G9C3ZLa0j9uODExuszARtXfIspwiFf6_SIhBRjtqYnbMP6OxTkCOzatVIFwo_ZvKXng-v9YbHC7QImI0wPUocom2fOUdkLzBdCuuqLeWCvnhdBDCP7y6Nom0B2WBx2ulnlpl6L6E2LGR3K-oopK_cAZRy81qUAjV0gsCOgB7zPshSSeMbz_Z9wZmKtolhh3GaHtCH28IGfOVQoVc_P32oMPIflLBLLPynlKv_f7ICcRA77JpOzuLSG0ZykfR8BSpf-D-Hoe6wvgSrBFQcm4UESLpGQ5lDokfUp-deGogVTA6U-X LN2R71SV4D6BVXaKJVNpISBZ0C0u34EQ0fWdtcw&Origin=https://teams.microsoft.com; files-version=20191015024; sessionId=597a5c74-c0a8-6a28-b9e9-1ac3e4cb26f8; TSAUTHCOOKIE=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IkJCOENlRlZxeWFHckdOdWVoSklpTDRkZmp6dyIsImtpZCI6IkJCOENlRlZxeWFHckdOdWVoSklpTDRkZmp6dyJ9.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.aLKqzoCn4-I0VeGeM_MvHITyyfH6b-2gqJYB3ZvhYlhANojYSh6hBY1rwzaUYboeSpPbflzqpWlbZFUsowLHfEOdwRbLQmYcGBKWx10YkwAVyNDQd4hvz61MrITyZqY3iUuNf8hqAeZSuGHgE-i7nLqEydTQrvnQFLG_qMF9KWhMidiT7p2ULyBdNhvwkDEHsq378lykz4ZCvk1tVOzWETcv9xz_zFP0tffz6aHZ4FTsK2lkZuHmSMxwTNzGaXwZYEP2rzXbuz70GMRdJRmAfMJMzMD97IeV5MD3p230-3dY_M-hZp9EyAb2h9sACDQ7XYBMeTFTzCVYfkJoSOEA_Q; ARRAffinity=0b20ba151314f86a0737223ef48ad813dc527c505a17f75b2d96c6573ffe5df1' \
  -d '{"inputParameters":[],"actionId":"e57e17c4-7b31-44ad-9062-8efc53c9a6b1","potentialAction":"{\"@type\":\"HttpPOST\",\"@id\":\"e57e17c4-7b31-44ad-9062-8efc53c9a6b1\",\"name\":\"Approve\",\"target\":\"https://401dd384.ngrok.io/teamshook/actions\",\"headers\":[{}],\"body\":\"Test Body\",\"bodyContentType\":\"\"}","name":"action/connector","integrationId":"lo6r5tcyqu","meta":"{\"connectorSenderGuid\":\"c16f86d9-12b6-40ff-8314-745c4023f48c\",\"providerAccountUniqueId\":null,\"connectorConfigurationAlternateId\":\"c36080ff202e4efab506e80383684041\"}","clientInfo":{"locale":"en-gb","country":"gb","platform":"Web","clientVersion":"1415/1.0.0.2019110122"}}'
```

We also tried different message formats and different users, but without any success.
If someone has an idea why that happen it would really cool to help us.

Thanks a lot.

---- edit

The captured curl of the executeAction call:

```
curl 'https://teams.microsoft.com/api/mt/emea/beta/users/connectors/19:2ff959fb46384b60806b4a3063940924@thread.skype;messageid=1574674903186/1574674903186/executeAction' -H 'authority: teams.microsoft.com' -H 'pragma: no-cache' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'x-ms-session-id: 35b0ec8d-066c-08cb-3abc-ea78a50b48cf' -H 'x-ms-scenario-id: 439' -H 'x-ms-user-type: user' -H 'x-ms-client-env: msteams-web-prod-ukso2-02' -H 'x-ms-client-type: web' -H 'authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IkJCOENlRlZxeWFHckdOdWVoSklpTDRkZmp6dyIsImtpZCI6IkJCOENlRlZxeWFHckdOdWVoSklpTDRkZmp6dyJ9.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.d7QIMoJ-lOJofbYaCsioBUPIUJMO9nWchS9h4egS4hmP5juMS-4Kf8g70uaIe_wngQFqDhXc2v0G37m8PtF0aPYt5LkE7TH1twNxJlO_Cplm3yLM1oCuJyeNDfPpjaJnRspIwsrhIUwrE5RC-gzVCyLHGKCxrhDzKr4aqLjNOO4uHk3PPDa9GvRmN-qowOc4KYlBo8Pv4dykIE6I9MkhlMabewIx5jOPSOJj2cBcup90i45t6DpmMrwgPVfhJCTJ8nqQ_jmqIelsISsfpLenWu0QfO7A2c96-KsflUdsJeLpyY2VyrAWh67UYLvGY1ojaiHdeT35TmNM-rg5glfMVw' -H 'content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'x-skypetoken: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEwMSIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1NzQ2NzI2MDIsImV4cCI6MTU3NDcwMTQwMSwic2t5cGVpZCI6Im9yZ2lkOjhhYzA4OGNmLWQ3MmYtNDFlNC05YzY4LTBlOTY3YjI1MzViNCIsInNjcCI6NzgwLCJjc2kiOiIxNTc0NjcyMzAxIiwidGlkIjoiMzYyMDdkMTMtNTA1OC00Njg4LThiZjktMzIwMTM5OTk1ODk0IiwicmduIjoiZW1lYSJ9.WV_2hEA7NQvGiPs6OSmIyt3-OMqZzAjV-EhZq52codhAbusEpjJOzHY1nBxxL3qC3NZzRAomjUHr31P3Yv3hDKE92jM_n4bEvnCKVYGSvKwXDQQFgFS-pYmU8Q8EFxhhZAtT6SJkXeh1_Pzhr9daQwHy0y4I_eW8PVjfrVGJnDcEXOH2YqFT71EwKMzUazGmayRqJh8npoAOJpL7LHRZyYo5KArOQrnN87eS9eCOEWGZtGQyt7goLD7A9CiaBeRovwG-OafHMnQOI1mLIlpvEEz5kxFp43h4d4O-l2YmY0CBj5MxlDMPqXnYXAyV8atwa0N0GR_PIdYvXCbl_69EPQ' -H 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36' -H 'x-ms-client-version: 1415/1.0.0.2019111310' -H 'x-ringoverride: general' -H 'origin: https://teams.microsoft.com' -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' -H 'referer: https://teams.microsoft.com/_' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,de;q=0.8' -H $'cookie: optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1529660782443r0.2799079385478569; IR_PI=1529660786364.usqgowm9e9g; brwsr=ef21e579-7cd8-3c29-bada-c9967030ccb9; LPVID=RmMmFkNjk5ZmRmZWVjNzBk; display-culture=de-DE; _ga=GA1.2.993109843.1535539108; WRUIDCD03072018=1948513313079677; __gads=ID=aa5a04581235989c:T=1547817653:S=ALNI_MZ__N-eFcHFk2f7gcWVfLEhcVtVJg; _mkto_trk=id:157-GQE-382&token:_mch-microsoft.com-1557562473465-90230; MC1=GUID=1809430531dc470ab5889c2130829947&HASH=1809&LV=201906&V=4&LU=1561124815979; _fbp=fb.1.1561386017962.594814471; MSCC=1564056930; ctm={\'pgv\':8232991868068086|\'vst\':3309208493223749|\'vstr\':5569381663943377|\'intr\':1568375851503|\'v\':1|\'lvst\':71908}; MUID=30503BCD438C6B431394362F478C68A1; WT_FPC=id=2ab27edf110839692921535511354465:lv=1570156567867:ss=1570156567867; MUIDB=30503BCD438C6B431394362F478C68A1; clocale=en-us; aamoptsegs=aam%3D10802490; AMCV_EA76ADE95776D2EC7F000101%40AdobeOrg=-179204249%7CMCIDTS%7C18028%7CMCMID%7C85519884052926733562433929802324639263%7CMCAAMLH-1573748769%7C6%7CMCAAMB-1573825495%7CRKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT-1573227895s%7CNONE%7CMCAID%7C2DD716958530F6F7-40000306A0019702%7CvVersion%7C3.3.0%7CMCCIDH%7C-1662673240; utag_main=v_id:016b89dbe48a008fafa26738cac003073007d06b00978$_sn:6$_ss:1$_st:1573228821833$ses_id:1573227021833%3Bexp-session$_pn:1%3Bexp-session; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; TSPREAUTHCOOKIE=true; deviceId=8036815e-0e2e-4aa0-9e95-7034718e0a65; firstTimeLaunch=1573228504173; TSREGIONCOOKIE=emea; TSAUTHCOOKIE=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IkJCOENlRlZxeWFHckdOdWVoSklpTDRkZmp6dyIsImtpZCI6IkJCOENlRlZxeWFHckdOdWVoSklpTDRkZmp6dyJ9.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.RVs7UcvitYkqtjAgg-tDRELPR7UOh1RxYLMz3fnYCFmwz8Bc3geDZ1MeuW9z2e_0bPiUqfos5Aza43L57CrxY9ySGd2T3UlT8mRpVhJc1gTMkF_cXaDVy67WUgUs62YHbZ3PUOKL23kZ4bFE665cE8jBGT8vsKaH5ufxdn3Ba81Bj-HX9fch9ynRKU1z6g7v_0cDBSWY_E95cqochFvMZmBeWIKpDDIDjVsnnT1cviG-APZPq4pEYjBxY1NK6zXeZkRIdmNq4h9lLAU9tVTulordJbqUmTgbJNubZxt0b7Pmmg8VjXbT3qkMT9ddH1oEI9RIlotmsZTjappxxLBvNQ; minimumVersionClientUpdateTries=0; authtoken=Bearer=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IkJCOENlRlZxeWFHckdOdWVoSklpTDRkZmp6dyIsImtpZCI6IkJCOENlRlZxeWFHckdOdWVoSklpTDRkZmp6dyJ9.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.d7QIMoJ-lOJofbYaCsioBUPIUJMO9nWchS9h4egS4hmP5juMS-4Kf8g70uaIe_wngQFqDhXc2v0G37m8PtF0aPYt5LkE7TH1twNxJlO_Cplm3yLM1oCuJyeNDfPpjaJnRspIwsrhIUwrE5RC-gzVCyLHGKCxrhDzKr4aqLjNOO4uHk3PPDa9GvRmN-qowOc4KYlBo8Pv4dykIE6I9MkhlMabewIx5jOPSOJj2cBcup90i45t6DpmMrwgPVfhJCTJ8nqQ_jmqIelsISsfpLenWu0QfO7A2c96-KsflUdsJeLpyY2VyrAWh67UYLvGY1ojaiHdeT35TmNM-rg5glfMVw&Origin=https://teams.microsoft.com; files-version=20191015024; visitBotInputMenuInChannel28%3Acc7e39e5-a336-43ec-956f-8c4a3326faae=firsttimevisit; sessionId=35b0ec8d-066c-08cb-3abc-ea78a50b48cf; ARRAffinity=92d0c4513bf71e4bdf5bd11c260c635040e50a681c1c4633e279ddba09044679' --data-binary '{"inputParameters":[{"id":"comment","value":"123123"}],"actionId":"faa584fb-532c-4c72-a8a3-57828dcd7ff6","potentialAction":"{\"@type\":\"HttpPOST\",\"@id\":\"faa584fb-532c-4c72-a8a3-57828dcd7ff6\",\"name\":\"OK\",\"target\":\"https://webhook.site/9375df39-4c54-4929-9d04-769d1d54cde8\",\"headers\":[],\"body\":\"\",\"bodyContentType\":\"\"}","name":"action/connector","integrationId":"ujl4uzt1op","meta":"{\"connectorSenderGuid\":\"9cbc95ef-5805-49d6-916a-b00d607986b0\",\"providerAccountUniqueId\":null,\"connectorConfigurationAlternateId\":\"febcfc0a762e4010a026124d9394bebd\"}","clientInfo":{"locale":"en-us","country":"us","platform":"Web","clientVersion":"1415/1.0.0.2019111310"}}' --compressed
```

And here is the log of the response:

```
precompiled-web-worker-cea5e26e7cd2899905ea.js:38 2019-11-25T09:41:57.638Z cdlwebworker: {"component":"CDLStateMachine","hostRendererId":"cdlwebworker","requestType":"database","message":"The state machine for handler tasks 0.10999999358318746 to be ready to process requests"}
precompiled-web-worker-cea5e26e7cd2899905ea.js:38 2019-11-25T09:41:58.442Z cdlwebworker: {"component":"CDLStateMachine","hostRendererId":"cdlwebworker","requestType":"database","message":"The state machine for handler tasks 0.03500000457279384 to be ready to process requests"}
angular.min.js:98 POST https://teams.microsoft.com/api/mt/emea/beta/users/connectors/19:2ff959fb46384b60806b4a3063940924@thread.skype;messageid=1574674903186/1574674903186/executeAction 403
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:98
r @ angular.min.js:93
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:90
f @ angular.min.js:126
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:126
$eval @ angular.min.js:141
$digest @ angular.min.js:138
(anonymous) @ msteams-web-ng1-services.min.js:1
$apply @ angular.min.js:141
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:269
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:1
angular.min.js:113 2019-11-25T09:42:03.490Z [O365ActionPaneController.makeHttpPOSTRequestForConnector()] Http invoke failed: {"data":{"errorCode":"Forbidden","message":"An unexpected error(Type = Forbidden) occurred. Please try again."},"status":403,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"https://teams.microsoft.com/api/mt/emea/beta/users/connectors/19:2ff959fb46384b60806b4a3063940924@thread.skype;messageid=1574674903186/1574674903186/executeAction","data":{"inputParameters":[{"id":"comment","value":"123123"}],"actionId":"faa584fb-532c-4c72-a8a3-57828dcd7ff6","potentialAction":"{\"@type\":\"HttpPOST\",\"@id\":\"faa584fb-532c-4c72-a8a3-57828dcd7ff6\",\"name\":\"OK\",\"target\":\"https://webhook.site/9375df39-4c54-4929-9d04-769d1d54cde8\",\"headers\":[],\"body\":\"\",\"bodyContentType\":\"\"}","name":"action/connector","integrationId":"ujl4uzt1op","meta":"{\"connectorSenderGuid\":\"9cbc95ef-5805-49d6-916a-b00d607986b0\",\"providerAccountUniqueId\":null,\"connectorConfigurationAlternateId\":\"febcfc0a762e4010a026124d9394bebd\"}","clientInfo":{"locale":"en-us","country":"us","platform":"Web","clientVersion":"1415/1.0.0.2019111310"}},"headers":{"X-Skypetoken":"pii","Authorization":"pii","Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8","X-RingOverride":"general","x-ms-scenario-id":"439","x-ms-user-type":"user","x-ms-client-type":"web","x-ms-client-env":"msteams-web-prod-ukso2-02","x-ms-client-version":"1415/1.0.0.2019111310","x-ms-session-id":"35b0ec8d-066c-08cb-3abc-ea78a50b48cf"},"counter":"ext_actionable_card_http_post","decrementNetworkRequests":null,"hostName":"teams.microsoft.com"},"statusText":""}
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:113
(anonymous) @ msteams-web-ng1-services.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ msteams-web-ng1-services.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ msteams-web-ng1.min.js:1
f @ angular.min.js:126
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:126
$eval @ angular.min.js:141
$digest @ angular.min.js:138
(anonymous) @ msteams-web-ng1-services.min.js:1
$apply @ angular.min.js:141
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:92
x @ angular.min.js:96
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:97
load (async)
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:97
r @ angular.min.js:93
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:90
f @ angular.min.js:126
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:126
$eval @ angular.min.js:141
$digest @ angular.min.js:138
(anonymous) @ msteams-web-ng1-services.min.js:1
$apply @ angular.min.js:141
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:269
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:1
precompiled-web-worker-cea5e26e7cd2899905ea.js:38 2019-11-25T09:42:28.459Z cdlwebworker: {"component":"CDLStateMachine","hostRendererId":"cdlwebworker","requestType":"database","message":"The state machine for handler tasks 0.09499999578110874 to be ready to process requests"}
```

Comment: Is the connector registered in the same account(tenant) where it is being tested? Could you please try creating the connector and testing it in the same tenant?

Comment: I have only one account where I test the connector. 
Where can I see my tenantid? I found one which was shown in a link of a third party connector: 36207d13-5058-4688-8bf9-320139995894

The flow I created the connector was:
Create a new app in the App Studio in MS Teams =>
Register a connector =>
Logged in the the Dev portal with my account

Thanks

Comment: Is the mailbox address important somehow? 
Because, when I open the url 'https://outlook.office.com/' my outlook online open and I see my inbox. But when I open 'https://outlook.office.com/connectors/home/login/' I get 500 with Mailbox address missing in URL
`{"errorType":"GroupMailboxAddressMissingException","errorMessage":"Mailbox address missing in URL","errorMessageFromProvider":null,"providerName":"","host":"DB7PR05MB5036","requestId":"7db73149-9354-437d-9872-c0e172a12103","time":"\/Date(1574173649042)\/","launchUrl":null}`

Comment: Can you try putting your targetURL to one of the urls in [webhook.site](http://webhook.site/#!/9375df39-4c54-4929-9d04-769d1d54cde8) and see if your request reaches there?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. We added the url to our connector, but still we get forbidden as result. To see if it works in general we did a call from postman.
We captured the executeAction and attached the response log to the question.

Comment: Could you please share the latest timestamp for the error? We are not able to use the logs as it was reported 15 days ago. Could you also share the channel link for the channel where the message was posted and the action id in the response corresponding to the time when action was made?

Comment: webhookUrl: "https://outlook.office.com/webhook/8fc4b02f-2d68-4b4f-afde-b61aa325ae90@36207d13-5058-4688-8bf9-320139995894/c16f86d9-12b6-40ff-8314-745c4023f48c/2b384aa677d84343992f1b038f0fedb4/f7bc25e5-eaaf-470e-b218-f02aa3000d71"
teamId: "19:27fec5913d2d459094c3e078731b41c2@thread.skype"
tid: "36207d13-5058-4688-8bf9-320139995894"

Comment: actionId: "0e9203e6-5958-46b9-a235-647a069b4139"  <br/>
response date: Wed, 27 Nov 2019 08:38:21 GMT  <br/>
integrationId: "6dmyabiyv4"


channel link: https://teams.microsoft.com/l/channel/19%3a27fec5913d2d459094c3e078731b41c2%40thread.skype/General?groupId=8fc4b02f-2d68-4b4f-afde-b61aa325ae90&tenantId=36207d13-5058-4688-8bf9-320139995894

Comment: Thanks for sharing the details. We have looked into it and the request seems to have been blocked with Error: Tenant 36207d13-5058-4688-8bf9-320139995894 DOES NOT allow connector Id {}
It looks like tenant settings access list does not have the Connector App listed, so Teams Backend is returning 403. Could you please check with your Tenant Admin to enable the connector ?

Comment: Now we have it. Thanks a lot. 
To connect the connector with our tenant we used the wrong upload. It was necessary to use Upload for XXX and not Upload for me or my teams. Also we added our domains under: https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/company-wide-settings/external-communications